# django forms do not always save changes to the database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-forms

I am working on a django app that has a postgresql backend. I have a python script that goes through a process that ultimately launches several web forms, one for each record in a table in the database that needs to be modified. The script iterates over a list of IDs to determine which records need to be modified and launches the forms all at once. I notice that some of the forms will accept and save changes, whereas some of the forms do not save the changes. I also notice with a form that initially saves changes, if I reload the form and try to make additional changes, those do not get saved. I'm not sure what is wrong? New to using django. Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>     
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      {% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'update/css/forms.css' %}" />
  </head>
 <body>
    {% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
        <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
   <div><label class="page_header">{{title}}<label><div>  
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <div><fieldset class="fieldset">
            <legend class="legend">Create Map Index Record</legend>
            {% csrf_token %}
             {% for field in form_mapindex.hidden_fields %}
                {{ field }}
                <br>
            {% endfor %}

            {% for field in form_mapindex.visible_fields %}
                <label class="formlabel">{{ field.label_tag }} 
                <br>
                {{ field }}
                <br>
            {% endfor %}

            <br><button class="button" type="submit">Save Record</button>
        </fieldset></div>
        {% if form.errors %}
            {% for field in form %}
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

here is the forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Mapindex

class MapIndexForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mapindex
        fields = ['objectid', 'sheetlabel', 'image_path_filename', 'county', 'route', 'map_sheet_desc', 'drawingdate',
                  'index_map_filepath', 'grantor_box_filepath', 'control_map_filepath', 'info_sheet_filepath', 'mapdatum']

        widgets = {'objectid': forms.HiddenInput(),
                   'drawingdate': forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(1900, 2021))}

        labels = {
            'sheetlabel': 'Sheet Label',
            'image_path_filename': 'PDF Filepath',
            'county': 'County',
            'route': 'Route',
            'map_sheet_desc': 'Map Sheet Description',
            'drawingdate': 'Drawing Date',
            'index_map_filepath': 'Index Map Filepath',
            'grantor_box_filepath': 'Grantor Box Filepath',
            'control_map_filepath': 'Control Map Filepath',
            'info_sheet_filepath': 'Info Sheet Filepath',
            'mapdatum': 'Map Datum'
        }
```

here is views.py:

```
from django.http import request, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect, render_to_response
from .models import Mapindex as MapIndexModel
from .forms import MapIndexForm
from django.contrib import messages


def mapindex_edit(request, row_id):
    record = get_object_or_404(MapIndexModel, pk=row_id)
    record.refresh_from_db()
    form_mapindex = MapIndexForm(request.POST or None, instance=record)

    if request.POST:
        if form_mapindex.is_valid():
            print 'form is valid'
            form_mapindex.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Record Saved!')
        else:
            print 'form is not valid'

    return render(request, 'edit.html', {
        'title': 'Map Index Update Form',
        'form_mapindex': form_mapindex
    })
```

and here is a snippet from the python script that launches the forms:

```
for oid in new_oid_list:
        url = 'http://sv04gis.ct.dot.ca.gov/mapindex/update/' + str(oid)
        webbrowser.open(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes in your views,

```
def mapindex_edit(request, row_id):
    record = get_object_or_404(MapIndexModel, pk=row_id)
    record.refresh_from_db()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_mapindex = MapIndexForm(request.POST or None, instance=record)  
        if form_mapindex.is_valid():
            form_mapindex.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Record Saved!')
    else:
        form_mapindex = MapIndexForm()
    return render(request, 'edit.html', { 'title': 'Map Index Update Form', 'form_mapindex': form_mapindex })
```